# Left Join two MYSQL databases

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to join two Mysql databases, but I am getting the following error:

> SELECT command denied to user 'sj'@'localhost' for table 'joborders'

below are how my databases are listed:

- db1 - database  sjb  table joborders
- db - database sj Table  users

And this is my code:

```
    $query = "SELECT db1.users.username,  db.joborders.usern, db.joborders.job_title ".
    "FROM db.joborders LEFT JOIN db1.users ".
"ON db.joborders.usern = dbi.users.username"; 

    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo $row['usern']. " - ". $row['job_title'];
```

I have tried re-writing this several different ways but i just keep getting the same error.

Comment: This a privileges issue not a join problem.

Comment: They both have the privileges set to all, so what else could it be, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You might have a typo in your table names

```
"ON db.joborders.usern = dbi.users.username";
```

replace i with 1

instead of telling you that the 'dbi' table doesn't exist, the error message indicates that the command was denied -- as though you don't have permissions

Post the schemas if you are not sure,also is `usern` a column?
Are you sure `db1.users_username`,  `db.joborders_usern` the table names are not like this,with underline?

db1 - database sjb table joborders

db - database sj Table users

From this info names should be `sjb.joborders`,`sj.users` and so on.